Is there any name for Zoroastrians in the Talmud?
I have come across a name for Zoroastrian priests (chavarim, magosim) in the Talmud, but not specifically for the followers of Zoroastrianism.
Did they have any specific name?

Persians, or goyim or Nochrim usually. What I mean is that the average non-Jewish Persian was a Zoroastrian, so they didn't have a specific name for them.

@Sholom precisely. That is the answer. (Or add an Aleph for Aramaic.)

@Sholom that word refers to the priests or magi of the Zoroastrians, as already mentioned by the OP.

@Harel13 Yes, my bad - I looked at the title without looking at the actual question. Although Tosafot on Gittin 17a says that חברים are an ״אומה״, but I’m not sure if they hold that חברים are Zoroastrians.
